# postgres exporting database file to preserve index

Tags: postgresql

I have been using postgres to build a large database for my research, and I need to export the database to allow my users to use the database I have developped.
In the past I have been exporting database in .csv file and it was a stable choice, but my users have all sorts of problem when import the .csv file, and settting up the database, and create index.
I am wondering if I can help users to preserve all the necessary information like index and view, in my database export, so users can just import the file and no need to touch the database I prepared for them. I am wondering exporting sql dump will help me do that?

Comment: `pg_dump` will do exactly that, but your users still need to _import_ that into a running Postgres server on their side

Comment: A pg_dump still needs to be imported.  "All sorts of problem" isn't very specific, they very well may have the same problem importing a dump as they do a importing a \copy.  Your users needs to have a certain minimum level of competence in order for *anything* to work.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, yeah, pg_dump reduce the complexity.